# List view items repeats in android

Tags: android, listview

I have displayed a Custom List-View but when i run it, the list-view items repeated 3 times(might be the array size).How can i make the List-View display non-repeated items?Below is my code.

```
public class lvAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
private Context context;

String festi,weekd,datee;
List<FestPOJO> listPhonebook = PublicHolidays.listOffests;

public lvAdapter(Context context, List<FestPOJO> listPhonebook) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listPhonebook = listPhonebook;
}

public int getCount() {
    return listPhonebook.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listPhonebook.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


  FestPOJO inst  = listPhonebook.get(position); 

    if (convertView == null) 

    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_row, null);
    }



    TextView tvContact = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContact);
    tvContact.setText(inst.getName());

    TextView tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMobile);
    tvPhone.setText(inst.getDay());

    TextView tvMail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMail);
    tvMail.setText(inst.getHalfdate());


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    System.out.println("getviewtypecount"+getCount());
    return super.getViewTypeCount();
}

   }
```

This is my FestPOJO class:

```
public class FestPOJO {
int weekend, opt, bank, year, id, date;
String name, month, day,halfdate;

public FestPOJO(String name, String day, String halfdate) {

    this.name = name;
    this.day = day;
    this.halfdate = halfdate;       
}

public String getHalfdate() {
    return halfdate;
}

public void setHalfdate(String halfdate) {
    this.halfdate = halfdate;
}

public int getWeekend() {
    return weekend;
}

public void setWeekend(int weekend) {
    this.weekend = weekend;
}

public int getOpt() {
    return opt;
}

public void setOpt(int opt) {
    this.opt = opt;
}

public int getBank() {
    return bank;
}

public void setBank(int bank) {
    this.bank = bank;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(int date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(String month) {
    this.month = month;
}

public String getDay() {
    return day;
}

public void setDay(String day) {
    this.day = day;
}
```

}

Any Help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Array might be having repeated values. So must ensure no repeated entries are there in array.

Comment: @UsamaSarwar The array values are not been repeated.i have checked it by printing in logcat and also queried it in sqlbrowser.

Answer (score 1):

use a ViewHolder in the Adapter or there will be wrong after scroll the listView

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{  
Context mContext;  
LinearLayout linearLayout = null;  
LayoutInflater inflater;  
TextView text;  

public MyAdapter(Context context) {  
    mContext = context;  
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);  
}  

@Override  
public int getCount() {  
    return listString.size();  
}  

@Override  
public int getItemViewType(int position) {  
   return positon;
}  

@Override  
public Object getItem(int arg0) {  
    return listString.get(arg0);  
}  

@Override  
public long getItemId(int position) {  
    return position;  
}  

@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    viewHolder1 holder1 = null;    

    if(convertView == null)  
    {   
        //no convertView create it the key is convertView.setTag  
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem1, parent, false);  
        holder1 = new viewHolder();  
        holder1.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);  
        convertView.setTag(holder1);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        //has convertViews the key is convertView.getTag();  
        holder1 = (viewHolder1) convertView.getTag();  
        holder1.textView.setText(Integer.toString(position));
    }  
    return convertView;  
}  

class viewHolder1{  
    TextView textView;  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right,  by reusing existing views. Is it possible that your underlying lists contains duplicates?  In this case you have to filter list to supress them.

Comment: The array values are not been repeated.i have checked it by printing in logcat and also queried it in sqlbrowser.